# Select newest entry from a joined MySQL table

Tags: sql, mysql, join, greatest-n-per-group

I have stock quantity information in my database.

1 table, "stock", holds the productid (sku) along with the quantity and the filename from where it came.

The other table, "stockfile", contains all the processed filenames along with dates.

Now I need to get all the products with their latest stock quantity values.

This gives me ALL the products multiple times with all their stock quantity (resulting in 300.000 records)

> SELECT stock.stockid, stock.sku, stock.quantity, stockfile.filename, stockfile.date
>   FROM stock
>   INNER JOIN stockfile ON stock.stockfileid = stockfile.stockfileid
>   ORDER BY `stock`.`sku` ASC

I already tried this:

> SELECT * FROM stock
>   INNER JOIN stockfile ON stock.stockfileid = stockfile.stockfileid
>   GROUP BY sku
>   HAVING stockfile.date = MAX( stockfile.date )
>   ORDER BY `stock`.`sku` ASC

But it did not work

**SHOW CREATE TABLE stock:**

> CREATE TABLE `stock` (
>    `stockid` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
>    `sku` char(25) NOT NULL,
>    `quantity` int(5) NOT NULL,
>    `creationdate` datetime NOT NULL,
>    `stockfileid` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
>    `touchdate` datetime NOT NULL,
>    PRIMARY KEY (`stockid`)
>   ) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=315169 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

**SHOW CREATE TABLE stockfile:**

> CREATE TABLE `stockfile` (
>    `stockfileid` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
>    `filename` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
>    `creationdate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
>    `touchdate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
>    `date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
>    `begindate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
>    `enddate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
>    PRIMARY KEY (`stockfileid`)
>   ) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=265 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

Comment: Please edit your question with the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE stock` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE stockfile`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an example of the frequently-asked "[greatest-n-per-group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group)" question that we see every week on StackOverflow.  Follow that tag to see other similar solutions.

```
SELECT s.*, f1.*
FROM stock s
INNER JOIN stockfile f1
  ON (s.stockfileid = f1.stockfileid)
LEFT OUTER JOIN stockfile f2
  ON (s.stockfileid = f2.stockfileid AND f1.date < f2.date)
WHERE f2.stockfileid IS NULL;
```

If there are multiple rows in `stockfile` that have the max date, you'll get them both in the result set.  To resolve this, you'd have to add some tie-breaker conditions into the join on `f2`.

---

Thanks for adding the `CREATE TABLE` info.  That's very helpful when you're asking SQL questions.

I see from the `AUTO_INCREMENT` table options that you have 315k rows in `stock` and only 265 rows in `stockfile`.  Your `stockfile` table is the parent in the relationship, and the `stock` table is the child, with a column `stockfileid` that references the primary key of `stockfile`.

So your original question was misleading.  You want the latest row from `stock`, not the latest row from `stockfile`.

```
SELECT f.*, s1.*
FROM stockfile f
INNER JOIN stock s1
  ON (f.stockfileid = s1.stockfileid)
LEFT OUTER JOIN stock s2
  ON (f.stockfileid = s2.stockfileid AND (s1.touchdate < s2.touchdate
      OR s1.touchdate = s2.touchdate AND s1.stockid < s2.stockid))
WHERE s2.stockid IS NULL;
```

I'm assuming you want "latest" to be relative to `touchdate`, so if you want to use `creationdate` instead, you can do the edit.

I've added a term to the join so that it resolves ties.  I know you said the dates are "practically unique" but as the saying goes, "[one in a million is next Tuesday](http://blogs.msdn.com/larryosterman/archive/2004/03/30/104165.aspx)."

---

Okay, I think I understand what you're trying to do now.  You want the most recent row per `sku`, but the `date` by which to compare them is in the referenced table `stockfile`.

```
SELECT s1.*, f1.*
FROM stock s1
JOIN stockfile f1 ON (s1.stockfileid = f1.stockfileid)
LEFT OUTER JOIN (stock s2 JOIN stockfile f2 ON (s2.stockfileid = f2.stockfileid))
  ON (s1.sku = s2.sku AND (f1.date < f2.date OR f1.date = f2.date AND f1.stockfileid < f2.stockfileid))
WHERE s2.sku IS NULL;
```

This does a self-join of `stock` to itself, looking for a row with the same `sku` and a more recent `date`.  When none is found, then `s1` contains the most recent row for its `sku`.  And each instance of `stock` has to join to its `stockfile` to get the `date`.

---

Re comment about optimization:  It's hard for me to test because I don't have tables populated with data matching yours, but I'd guess you should have the following indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX stock_sku ON stock(sku);
CREATE INDEX stock_stockfileid ON stock(stockfileid);
CREATE INDEX stockfile_date ON stockfile(date);
```

I'd suggest using `EXPLAIN` to analyze the query without the indexes, and then create one index at a time and re-analyze with `EXPLAIN` to see which one gives the most direct benefit.

Comment: I know, I've actually solved a similar problem thanks to stackoverflow. But your query still gives me 315.000 results :/

Comment: Then I would guess there are a lot of ties for the max date per stock.

Comment: A lot of ties? 
The "date" field is practically unique in the stockfile table.
Per date there can be about 100 records in the stock table

Comment: Hmm, but I can't use the touchdate from the "stock" table, the only date that matters is the "date" field in stockfile.

(touchdate and creationdate are fields to let me know when it was originally created and last edited.

A stockfile from last year can be re-imported today, which would results in old records having the highest touchdate)

Comment: That's exactly what I mean! :) (stock & stockfile could be the same table, but I've taught to deduplicate as much as possible)

Your query did the trick. The only problem now is that it takes about 250 seconds. Is there a way to speed it up? New index or so?

Comment: Ah yes, unfortunately I forgot I already made those indexes. So without them it takes ages, with them it takes "only" 250 seconds. Maybe I'll better create a new question to not go off-topic too much?

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.stockid, 
       s.sku, 
       s.quantity, 
       sf.filename, 
       sf.date
  FROM STOCK s
  JOIN STOCKFILE sf ON sf.stockfileid = s.stockfileid
  JOIN (SELECT t.stockfileid,
               MAX(t.date) 'max_date'
          FROM STOCKFILE t
      GROUP BY t.stockfileid) x ON x.stockfileid = sf.stockfileid
                               AND x.max_date = sf.date
```

Comment: I'm afraid this still gives me all 315.000 records.

Comment: I updated to add the `DISTINCT`, because the most likely reason is the rows are being duplicated because of the JOINs.

Comment: Hmm, even with the distinct it still gives me all the duplicate records.

Comment: @Jelle: That's impossible - DISTINCT is a synonym for GROUP BY - all the rows returned will be unique in some way, even if it is one column value.  The most likely reason is that you've got ties based on the maximum date.

Comment: I haven't defined any relations or ties in the database.

Comment: @skerit: ties == similar, have two or more matched records.  not tie as in link

Answer (score 0):

There are two common ways to accomplish this: a sub query or a self-join.

See [this example of selecting the group-wise maximum](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html) at the MySQL site.

Edit, an example using a subquery:

```
SELECT stock.stockid, stock.sku, stock.quantity,
       stockfile.filename, stockfile.date
FROM stock
INNER JOIN stockfile ON stock.stockfileid = stockfile.stockfileid
WHERE stockfile.date = (SELECT MAX(date) FROM stockfile);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from   stock
where  stockfileid in (
           select top 1 stockfileid
           from   stockfile
           order by date desc
       )
```

Comment: That won't work as is - you need to correlate the subquery.  Currently the subquery will return only one row, and you're getting the stockfileid, not the date which is what you're really after.

Comment: This is not valid SQL for MySQL:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.4/en/select.html

Comment: That too - need to use `LIMIT`, not `TOP`

Comment: So is the problem that each stock file doesn't contain a complete stock check so the latest stock number for a particular product might be in any of the files? The question doesn't seem entirely clear.

Comment: Indeed, not everything is in the newest stockfile. But even if it were I'd still need to get the latest stock quantity like this.